# Does Windows 8 Tablet support .net and VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-8, emulation

I want to run Visual Studio 10 on Windows 8 Tablet. Does it support? Or do I need to install some emulator for that.
I wanna get one if it really works as if it works on Windows PC

Answer (score 1):

Alisha welcome to the community. This is your first post and before moving ahead please read https://stackoverflow.com/help.

And here is your answer

***With Windows RT, you can install apps directly from the Windows Store, but you can't install desktop programs that you used with previous versions of Windows.***

Surface running Windows RT won't run your desktops apps where as surface running Windows Pro will be able to run your desktop apps also.

[Please check the comparison here](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/which-surface-is-right-for-you)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Windows 8 Pro tablet will run the VS IDE. Hope this helps.